# What do you call someone who studies Russia?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, academia, professions, russian

This is my first post and I was wondering what do you call someone who studies Russia For a living like has an academic researcher or Scholar. A sentence would be I work has a -word-. Thanks in advance for any and all help.

Comment: Please see  [this guidance from Stack Exchange Management](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/single-word-requests-crosswords-and-the-fight-against-mediocrity) about such questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word **Russologist** is used to refer to persons who are experts on Russia.

Examples:

> Stanford's most accomplished Russologist returns home, to cheers (...)
>
> I took McFaul's Russian Politics class back in 1996/1997, when he was still a rising Russologist.
>
> (...)Rice = Sovietologist (her PhD was actually on Czechoslovakia, but her subsequent specialization came studying the Soviet Union.) Mike McFaul = Russologist (his research has concentrated on the post-Soviet Union collapse, and specifically the transition from Communism to what he hoped would be a liberal democracy (...)

Source: [www.thecardboard.org](http://thecardboard.org/board/index.php?PHPSESSID=nfhdsa7sg8e574uo1e68786264&topic=9820.msg87472#msg87472)

> Poet, translator and russologist Dr. Sajal Dey hails from Kolkata, West Bengal.

Source: https://milaplitfest.com/sajal-dey/

> A distinguished Russologist, Jiri Valenta is a former consultant to the Reagan administration and among the few members (...)

Source: http://www.israelnationalnews.com/Articles/Article.aspx/20646

> Most foreign observers who knew Russia well (...) shared the belief that Russia was not doomed to perdition. They included [Otto Hoetzsch](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otto_Hoetzsch), the leading German Russologist of his generation, (...)

Source: [google books](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=kTh-Abva-S4C&pg=PA53&lpg=PA53&dq=russologist&source=bl&ots=xo2GSC_gzG&sig=3o1dHA9dQSs3fRXeqz2MB4pLHc0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiO4efm6OfXAhWLK48KHVOZCdk4ChDoAQgiMAk#v=onepage&q=russologist&f=false)

More examples of use online: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=russologist

Comment: Ah, for the good old days. Sovietologist and Kremlinologist are slight more euphonious to my ears than Russologist.

Comment: I suppose the word 'Russologist' gained (or regained) prominence after the collapse of the Soviet Union, @James McLeod.

Comment: Yeah but, does anybody *say* that? It also seems to be slanted towards politics? Why not just historian or sociologist? They're experts on *all* things Russian? There's only one man who's *that* good, but he doesn't *always* drink Dos Equis... a made up word from 1997? Is there Americanoligy? Americanolgists? ...

Comment: Very true @Mazura: it does seem slanted towards political studies. Maybe specialisation on one country in one field of knowledge is not even ideal? However I was mainly establishing that the word "Russologist" is actually being used to describe the 'Russia expert' and learned a new word in the process of answering OP's question! According to the answer by 1006a, the word 'Americanist' is used to describe a scholar (often political scientist) whose speciality is the USA.

Answer (score 0):

The term I have heard in academia in the US is [***Russianist***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Russianist), which Wiktionary defines as

> A person who studies Russian language, culture or history.

[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/russianist) offers the example sentence

> *‘The book is nothing less than "a celebration of personality," to cite the apt formulation of the distinguished **Russianist** John B. Dunlop.’*

Presumably this was chosen to parallel the somewhat more common term [*Americanist*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/americanist), used for scholars (often political scientists) who study the US specifically.